# Do puppies "grow into their feet"?

Tags: dogs, growing

Some puppies seem to have feet to big for their body.  I have often heard that this is an indicator of a dog that will grow to be a larger dog.  Is there any truth to this idea?  Is a the size of a puppies feet in relation to their body, really an indicator of adult size?

Comment: I have no hard evidence to support this, nor do I have a long experience of raising dogs from pups to adults, so I can't answer definitively, but for both of my pups their feet size did seem to correlate to their adult size.

Answer (score 3):

The surest indication of a pup's eventual size is the size of his same sex parent, if he is purebred.  It's a big guess if he is a mix.

I can say definitively that paw size is not always an indicator of the finished size of the dog.  I have one purebred German shepherd with huge feet, twice as big as the next dog (also purebred German shepherd), and the bigger one is the one with the smaller feet.  People are always asking me if he's going to grow into his feet.  No, he is full grown.  He just comes from a variety of German shepherd that are large boned and therefore have large feet.  He also has a comparitavely big head, just like his parents.